# quicksand jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, quicksand

I am having hard times using the quicksand jquery plugin for flirtable portfolio.
I am on the verge of giving up this plugin but will be happy to know that I am wrong and there is a solution to my problem.

My problem is that my quicksand is working on my local computer but the same exact code is not working on a remote server.

also the plugin (on my local machine) is working only using this version of Jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Tried to put an updated code for the latest version and nothing works.
I dont know where is my problem?

can anyone help?

This is a link to the specific page:
http://clients.tipoos.com/bs/portfolio.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK so I found the problem myself finally.
The problem was with my Notepad++ which saved the files as
UTF-8 without BOM which somehow minified my JS file and caused my JS comments to 
comment the whole code when it was uploaded to the server.
I took the comments off and it worked

regardless - I stopped working with quicksand for filtering portfolio
and moved to isotope
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/
which was much better for me.

if you want to use it for commercial use you must pay $25 but it worth every cent.

hope that helps anyone..

Comment: It's not uncommon for good libraries to have a price attached to them.  Isotope was developed by David Desandro, who is a top client side developer.  As far as those free libraries go, you often get what you pay for!